# php jquery include files

Tags: php, jquery

I know that a you put the reference to jquery between the head tags as below.

```
Script src="js/jquery-1.3.2-full.js" type="text/javascript"
```

But on a php page with no head tags, where would I place the reference?

thanks

Rifki

Answer (score 0):

You don't hav to put them in the head-tags but it's recomended.
Why don't you structure your php-output with full html?

Comment: Yes you have to. `<script>` tags outside of the `<head>` will result in a buggy page that won't work in some browsers.

Comment: So i could add some head tags to my php page, and this wouldnt affect my php code?

Comment: Some very old browser like Netscape 4.

Comment: @NullUserException Not true (maybe for some really ancient browsers). It is actually recommended to put script tags for certain javascript libraries at the bottom of HTML right before </body>.

Comment: @Richard I personally had JS breaking when inserted out of the head. Since then I haven't put them anywhere but the `<head>`.

Comment: @NullUserException : there are just some things js can't do when included in the body, but barring those actions, having it in the body _does_ work, and might I say flawlessly in every browser supporting javascript for years and years.